# NSURLConnection delegate creation

Tags: ios, xcode, delegates

Is there an automatic way to create a NSURLConnection delegate in Xcode 4.5.2 for iOS? By that I mean that I added a new Class and indicated its Class as NSURLConnection in Xcode. But no delegate file(s) with corresponding delegate methods was created. Am I supposed to manually do that, or what? And if so, do I just add the delegate methods to the files that were created for me (BSUrl.h/.m)?

I don't think I need a UIWebView because I do not want to view the page I request, but only to parse it (with NSRegularExpressionSearch and NSTextCheckingResult, I hope). But if the lack of a UIWebView is the problem, please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add manually. You can create a custom NSURLConnection and create custom delegates, protocols to be implemented, or wharever you want. Also you can make a Category of NSURLConnection. If you re interesting, read more here: http://developer.apple.com/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Category.html